# How do I run a java program as an admin?

Tags: java, file-io

In a java program I'm making I need to edit the etc/hosts file, however I get an IOException error when I try to do so because access is denied. I googled it and it seems that I need to run the java program with administrator permissions. How do I do that?

Comment: On what operating system? Also, do you mean from another java program or just as a user running a java program?

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca. And I'm running it from the visual studios terminal.

Comment: What makes you think you need admin permissions? It sounds like it could just be a file permission issue. Why don't you post the full error message and let us see what the problem is instead of deciding it for us?

Comment: @ MarsAtomic it's an IOException, and when I printed the error trace it said that access to etc/hosts is denied. I thought I would need to run the .java file as an admin to access the file, but if you know of another method that would be great.